# web api - Hold piece of data on subsequent request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using web api with angualrjs and asp.net identity for **authentication** .

When using asp.net mvc, We will use session to hold some data for the subsequent request. Say for example, user account id.

In web api, how so I implement this? **I don't want to implement session in web api**. I need and alternate solution for this one.

Need to consider security aspect too.

Comment: Since you've specified you need it to be secure, and session isn't an option but you still want it to persist, what's wrong with storing the data in a db?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [claims-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity) authorization. For example, [you can integrate OAuth2 using OWIN-based packages in your solution](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server).

Comment: Yes, thank you. But whatever I am adding claims on createidentity only available through out the application and for the subsequent request. I need to add/update claims and should be available for the subsequent request.. Is that possible? I've tried to add/Update claims. But for the subsequent request, claims are vanished (whatever added dynamically)

Comment: @JeevaJsb You're doing something wrong. Claims are added to the token sent to the client, and they remain *as is* for the entire life of the token...

Comment: if i add claims inside this 'GenerateUserIdentityAsync' method after creating the identity, it works fine for the subsequent request. But if i add the claims anywhere (for example when i update user profile), then next request the added claims vanished..

Comment: @JeevaJsb Yes, because claims are added to the token. You should refresh the token someway if you add new claims...